# Symfony 5 - One entity, one Repository and two Databases

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem querying my database via Symfony Repository.
If I don't specify a repository

```
/**
 * ProductsText
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="products_text")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
```

i can select one of my databases by using Doctrine like this:

```
->getRepository(ProductsText::class, "db1").
```

But if i declare the repository:

```
/**
 * ProductsText
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="products_text")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Product\ProductsTextRepository")
 */
```

It only selects the database from which I pulled the entity from.
I can't use two different entities because the user selects the "database" when logging in. Unfortunately, I can't merge the two databases yet either, as they are not multi-tenant.

My guess is that I can solve the problem by keeping the registry from the repository in general. My previous attempts unfortunately ended up with the front end no longer loading.

Works, but only for one database:

```
class ProductsTextRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, ProductsText::class);
    }
```

Did not works:

```
class TbProductsTextRepository
{
  /**
   * @var EntityRepository
   */
  private $repository;

  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
  {
      $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(TbProductsText::class);
  }
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand the mechanics of how the repositorys are regestrated.

I use:

- Symfony 5.2
- Doctrine 2.2
- Doctrine ORM 2.8
- Doctrine Migrations Bundle 3.0

Comment: There is a good explanation here https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html.

Comment: I had already read that. That is also not the problem. But the use of the repositories in which I have specific queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by not "registering" the repository.
By using EntityRepository and without a construct, I can use the repository for both databases.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;


class TbProductsTextRepository extends EntityRepository
{
```

Comment: Glad you got it working.  The ServiceEntityRepository is fundamentally broken when it comes to having an entity mapped by multiple entity managers.  Only the first entity manager will ever be used.  I suspect you also had to exclude your repositories from autowire as well.